# is cakephp 2.0 faster than 1.3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

Since last February my cloud provider only supports CakePhp 2.0 even though six months ago they used Cakephp 1.3, now I have to decide if I should move to version 2.0 or keep using 1.3. I read all the official migration document and it seems good enough. But the main issue is if it really worth the effort in terms of speed, does cakephp 2.0 faster than 1.3?

I couldn't find a Pros vs Cons about the new version 2.0 or a benchmark or something, all I have found are tutorial about doing the migration but not something to convince me on why I should migrate form 1.3 to 2.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It is much faster and that should be obviously for multiple simple reasons. All the php4 OOP-quirks were dropped, the whole code re-organized and tuned, most things are lazy-loaded now.

Read this

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/new-features-in-cakephp-2-0.html

Besides the performance improvement I would update simply because of the improvements and new features.